# Yolov5 How to find pixel size of objects detected?

Tags: yolo, yolov5

I'm looking to make yolov5 detect.py output the size of the objects found inside the bounding boxes. However, I cannot find the correct variable, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!
link to code in github : https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py

Comment: I think, need more information and your code to answer your question. see the below guides. [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) / [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Edited, now containing link to code and more descriptive title